# Request is not forwarded from jsp page to dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Hello I'm learning `Spring MVC` from a tutorial site, I have situation where when I submit my html from `jsp` page it should get processed and give back success page, but when I'm submitting my form it is giving me `404 error`. So some body please help me how I can solve my problem below is my complete code.

Initially when I give request as http://localhost:3399/FristSpringMVCProject/admissionForm.html
my request is getting processed well and giving me the requested form page, but when Im trying to submit the form it is throwing the following error, I have attached image file of that error below at the ending of the post.

This is my **web.xml** file
    -----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>FristSpringMVCProject</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

This is my Dispatcher Servlet **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**
    -----------------------------------------------------------

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">  
        <context:component-scan  base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />  
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
       <!-- <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
       <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller.HelloController"></bean> -->

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />  
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
        </bean>  
    </beans>
```

This is my Front Controller **StudentAdmissionController.java**
    -----------------------------------------------------------

```
package com.gontuseries.hellocontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm(){
        System.out.println("inside getAdmissionForm");
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
    return model;
}

    @RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student") String student){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        model.addObject("message","Thanks for registering with us");
        model.addObject("student",student);
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is my Student `Bean` **Student.java**
    ------------------------------------

```
package com.gontuseries.hellocontroller;

public class Student {
private String name;
private String place;
public String getName(){
return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}
public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
}
```

This is my **AdmissionForm.jsp**
    ----------------------------

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please fill following details to complete registration</h1>
<form action="/FirstSpringMVCProject/submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">

<p>Student's Name : <input type="text" name="name"/></p>

<p>Place : <input type="text" name="place"/></p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Details"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>

This is my AdmissionSuccess.jsp
-------------------------------

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your request have been processed successfully</h1>
<h2>${message}</h2>
<h2>with following details...</h2>
<h3>Name : ${student.name}</h3>
<h3>Place : ${student.place}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

And this the error I'm getting when I submit Form page
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest adding `BindingResult result` after `@ModelAttribute('student') student` in the `studentAdmissionForm` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your shared code. Also your post needs correction as it is mixing up the code and your comments. 
I would like to point out few corrections.

1. AdmissionForm.jsp
   `<form action="submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">` should be enough in jsp.
2. StudentAdmissionController.java  `@RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student){` You should take the Student object only. you are taking String Student.
3. AdmissionForm.jsp

`<h3>Name : ${student.name}</h3>
<h3>Place : ${student.place}</h3>`
This will not work as you are setting String in controller.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Can you please accept the answer also?

Comment: Yeah I have modified my code with your answer, and It resolved my problem.Thank you for your quick reply